# In Drude model of conduction, are electrons moving across the conductive object?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, electric-current, conductors

As I understood, Drude model explains an electrical current as a chain of momentum transfer between electrons; In this sense, does a single electron leave its atom and move forming the electrical current, or does it only nudge a neighboring electron, moving a wave of momentum  transfers across the object, and staying, the electron that it, with its own atom. In other words, does a current in this model produce an magnetic field. I know the answer must be yes, but I can't quite connect all the dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you read of " chain of momentum transfer between electrons" this seems not the Drude model, where the electrons  in metal are treated as "gas" the e are accelerated by E, but the collide withe the ions of the metal so the are slowed down  there is a real mean velocity of the electrons, look at the picture in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model

Comment: I read it in the wikipedia article about Electrical Conductors, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_conductor, second paragraph.

Comment: I then realized, it is an actual transfer of momentum and electron, from one metal atom to a near by one, making it an actual current with actual moving charged, with sum vector velocity and hence magnetic field.

Comment: thanks for the answer.